# How did dragons come into existence?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, dragons

How were the dragons created? Did some God create them?

For example, we know that Melkor created the Dragons in Arda.

Is there something similar in the world of George Martin's?

Comment: In terms of the ultimate origin of dragons this question can't be answered because there isn't even any evidence [that the gods exist](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43468/17815) let alone what they may have created.

Comment: Moreover, I believe GRRM has said that there never will be any evidence of any god's existence.

Comment: They came in a spaceship, sent by their parents from the dying world of Krypton. They can fly and breathe fire because of the planet's yellow sun.

Comment: I think this kind of question goes against the spirit of ASoIaF. There are no answers in the books about almost nothing, only hints and folk tales. I'd say GRRM isn't interested in providing this kind of backstory, but that's my (unsupported) opinion. ASoIaF isn't a tale like Lord of the Rings, which has a creation myth that more or less corresponds to the truth.

Comment: When a mommy dragon and a daddy dragon really like each other...

Comment: Why couldn't dragons have been created in the same way as all other life in that world?

Comment: I haven't seen anything magical about Dragons yet. They are seen as some magical creatures in most Universes but not in ASOIF. 

They spit fire which is possible in an animal biologically. That alone doesn't make them magical. Evolution and natural selection brought them into existence I guess. 

As for Dany's dragon, their BIRTH was magical, not them.

Comment: @user24620 - No, they breathe fire because of the yellow sun - they can fly because Krypton was a bigger planet, thus stronger gravity effects.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Out of the original 3 [dragons](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragons) of the Targaryen conquerors, only Balerion came from Valyria. Meraxes and Vhagar were born on Dragonstone.

Other than that there is no information or "talk" on the origins of dragons. While they are connected to magic and seen as magical, they're also seen as animals. The people of Westeros don't discuss the origin of "cows" or "lions".

Everything about Valyria and its fall seems - even in universe - to be shrouded in myth and legend; as such we know very little about it.

AFAIK - and I've read pretty much everything connected to ASOIAF - [Valyria](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyria) in general has been mentioned only indirectly, and the origin of dragons hasn't been touched on at all.

Comment: I disagree with your point about people seeing Dragons as non-magical like a 'cow' or a 'lion'. Though they are (seemingly) non-existent, they are still very much seen as magical beings.

Comment: True, you've a point, and I'll make an edit tomorrow.

Comment: +1 _The people of Westeros don't discuss the origin of "cows" or "lions"_ Well maybe it's time we start asking some serious questions!

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Only Balerion was born in ancient Valyria. He was among the Five dragons brought to Dragonstone by Aenar Targaryen. Vhagar and Meraxes however were born on Dragonstone and were much younger than Balerion.

Comment: @Daft “SAM: Where are you from? What great power begat you? What beguiling mysteries are concealed ”neath you stoic and heartfelt silence? COW: *Moooooo*”

Answer (score 19):

> Once there were two moons in the sky, but one wandered too close to
>   the sun and cracked from the heat. A thousand thousand dragons poured
>   forth, and drank the fire of the sun. That is why dragons breathe
>   flame. One day the other moon will kiss the sun too, and then it will
>   crack and the dragons will return. -- GOT page 235

It is known.

Comment: Can you add which chapter that quote is from?

Comment: Daenerys :-) I'll addthe page number

Comment: It is known ...

Comment: @SystemDown: i posted this answer, just because i wanted to post a comment like yours.

Comment: It's only a myth, so what "is known"?

Comment: @Mithoron that's what Dany's dothraki hand maids say, "it is known".

Comment: @Mithoron The Dothraki say "It is known" when they axiomatically accept something as hard fact and unconditional truth. Things that are known are not questioned and those who do question them are smiled upon with pity, like little misguided  children. Further it seems appropriate in Dothraki culture to strengthen the claim to truth and display ones approval by confirming the axiom by answering "It is known."

Answer (score 16):

Here are some quotes from the books themselves:

> She had heard that the first dragons had come from the east, from the Shadow Lands beyond Asshai and the islands of the Jade Sea. Perhaps some were still living there, in realms strange and wild. (A Game of Thrones, Daenerys III)
>
> “Firewyrms. Some say they are akin to dragons, for wyrms breathe fire too. Instead of soaring through the sky, they bore through stone and soil. If the old tales can be believed, there were wyrms amongst the Fourteen Flames even before the dragons came. The young ones are no larger than that skinny arm of yours, but they can grow to monstrous size and have no love for men.” (A Feast for Crows, Arya II)

The Game of Thrones season 1 featurette ["Valyria and the Dragons"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdehV-AUM40) confirms that the Valyrians did find dragons in the Fourteen Flames, though I'm not sure if it is really considered canonical.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what we have from *The World of Ice and Fire*:

> ## The Rise of valyria
>
> ...
> In such fragments of Barth’s *Unnatural History* as remain, the septon appears to have
>   considered various legends examining the origins of dragons and how they came to be
>   controlled by the Valyrians. The Valyrians themselves claimed that dragons sprang forth as
>   the children of the Fourteen Flames, while in Qarth the tales state that there was once a
>   second moon in the sky. One day this moon was scalded by the sun and cracked like an egg,
>   and a million dragons poured forth. In Asshai, the tales are many and confused, but certain
>   texts—all impossibly ancient—claim that dragons first came from the Shadow, a place
>   where all of our learning fails us. These Asshai’i histories say that a people so ancient they
>   had no name first tamed dragons in the Shadow and brought them to Valyria, teaching the
>   Valyrians their arts before departing from the annals.
>   Yet if men in the Shadow had tamed dragons first, why did they not conquer as the
>   Valyrians did? It seems likelier that the Valyrian tale is the truest. But there were dragons
>   in Westeros, once, long before the Targaryens came, as our own legends and histories tell
>   us. If dragons did first spring from the Fourteen Flames, they must have been spread across
>   much of the known world before they were tamed. And, in fact, there is evidence for this,
>   as dragon bones have been found as far north as Ib, and even in the jungles of Sothoryos.
>   But the Valyrians harnessed and subjugated them as no one else could.
> <sup>*-The World of Ice and Fire, The Rise of Valyria.*</sup>